# Reference subsets (columns) of a table in Excel

Tags: mysql, database, vba, excel

I have a very large table in Excel with 200 columns about some students.

The first 10 columns identifies the student by name, age, etc.

The remaining 190 columns can be split into categories.

So my question is whether it is possible to create new sheets which duplicates some columns from the table, so I can split the table into 10 tables instead of having everything in the same table?

I know I can do this manually, but the problem is that the data set will be updated in the future, so I wonder if it is possible to use references or something like that?

If it is not possible, how would you solve such problem? Would you populate everything to a database (MySQL? Oracle?) and then extract in the sheets? The problem is also that I have to create some additional columns in each sheet, so I can not just override all content in a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're seeking for some subsets of your data, you could transform the Range into a Table, load it to Excel Power Query and get rid of the columns you don't need.

Then load it again to another Sheet of your choice.

You can repeat this process as wished.